# R DBI all db operations give verbose output, how to turn off?

Tags: r, dbi

I'm using `DBI` and `odbc` on Win 10 to access a Snowflake DB and I don't know what I did but all of my DB queries and even the connection are giving verbose output where yesterday it wasn't.  It's not a big deal, but it's flooding my console in Rstudio and is just kind of annoying.  I searched the DBI and odbc pdf on CRAN for "verbose" and "debug" and neither word appears.

`getOption('verbose')` comes back as `FALSE`

`curl::curl_options()[['verbose']]` returns 41

running `curl::curl_download("example.com",'blah.del')` doesn't return any verbosity.

Opening a new instance of Rstudio gives the same behavior.

However, using `RPostgres` to connect to a Postgres db is not returning verbose results.

Any other ideas on how to turn off the verbosity?

Here are a few lines I'm getting back in case they're relevant:

```
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.268 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "CLIENT_STORE_TEMPORARY_CREDENTIAL"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.269 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "ConnectFunctions"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.269 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "CPTIMEOUT"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.269 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "CURLVerboseMode"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.269 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "DEFAULT_BINARY_SIZE"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.270 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "DEFAULT_VARCHAR_SIZE"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.270 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "DriverODBCVer"
    2021-05-19T13:11:54.270 INFO  412 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionSettings::MergeMapContents: Optional setting: "EnablePidLogFileNames"
```

Comment: I don't think `DBI` or `odbc` are responsible for those, my guess is that it's the specific Simba driver itself. That's pretty frustrating, but I think you'll have to reach out to the ODBC driver (not R) maintainers for how to silence it. (I don't know who or how, unfortunately.)

Comment: https://simba.wpengine.com/products/SEN/doc/Client-Server_user_guide/content/clientserver/configuringsimbaclientodbc/simbaclientodbcconfigurationoptions.htm suggests that you can change `LogLevel` to reduce logging messages; I'm still confused, though, since they allege that the default value is `LOG_OFF` (no messages).

Comment: Did you find any more information on this, DeanMacGregor? I know I didn't offer any resolution, but it would be good if you added any insights you found.

Comment: @r2evans no, for unrelated reasons, we're not continuing with snowflake so it's moot for me at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Configuration parameters and LogLevel sections in https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html

You can fix the where the logs get piped to or just turn them off in the Windows registry

```
regedit -> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Snowflake\Driver

set LogPath = C:\Users\<YOUR ACCOUNT>\Documents\Snowflake ODBC Driver\log
```

and/or

```
set LogLevel = 0
```

I experienced the same issue when my sys-admin moved me to a new user account. Turns out that Snowflake had lost access to its logging file as the directory had changed. The same thing had previously only happened on a second (or greater) instance of R, presumably because the first instance locked up the logging file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the solution I used on the Snowflake community pages: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/ODBC-log-activity-showing-in-RStudio-Console-window

And here it is (for Windows) pasted here for reference. I followed these point-and-click instructions, and this resolved the problem for me.

Pasted text begin:

The solution for this issue is to check the existing path and folder structure for the ODBC Driver's LogPath setting.

In a Windows environment, please check the following:

1. Open Regedit (the app on my computer was called Registry Edit)
2. Navigate to the registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Snowflake\Driver
3. Examine the Data value for the key LogPath
4. Confirm that the folder path to the specified value in Step 3 exists and that the user who is running the RStudio application has write access to this location. If necessary adjust the LogPath to a writable location, such as C:\temp
5. Changes to the Windows Registry take effect upon closing the dialog box, so no further saving is needed. Upon making changes in step 4, restart RStudio and re-run the application code that connects to Snowflake and confirm that the INFO level ODBC output is no longer displayed in the console window in RStudio